# Can I display themed clothing together?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* is it possible to display themed clothing together in the same display? For example, if I had a themed shirt, pants, hat, etc could I place them all in the same spot on the floor to create a mannequin or other such display with them all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to display clothing together, however it requires a [mannequin](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Mannequin). There are only 4 per player in the game. Each one can be equipped with a hat, accessory, top, bottom, socks and shoes.

They are acquired from Sable, Mabel, Labelle and Gracie.

Quoting the [AC Wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Mannequin#How_to_Get_Mannequins):

- Sable's mannequin is obtained by becoming friends with her. The player must also have purchased at least 50 items from the Able Sisters shop. The earliest this mannequin can be achieved is by the tenth conversation with Sable.
- Mabel's mannequin is obtained by purchasing 51 clothing items in the Able Sisters shop.
- Labelle's mannequin is obtained by buying at least one accessory from her a day, over 31 days. The purchases do not have to be made on consecutive days.
- Gracie's mannequin is received when the player makes their first purchase on Gracie's floor of T&T Emporium.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid not. You have to get them (mannequins) from tasks in the game. One of the easiest is probably befriending Sable which you're going to do anyway if you want qrcodes to work. Just keep talking to her everyday. I'm sorry if any of this information is incorrect, I'm parroting what I've read haha. Good luck!